# Event handlers in Word VBA - MailMergeRecordMerge

Tags: vba, events, ms-word, eventhandler

I get that VBA in Word has a range of Event Handlers to trigger things when specific events occur in the document, but I cannot for the life of me get any of them to work at all.

I need to update a field on each record of a mail merge,  but I cannot get it to run.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
Private Sub Document_MailMergeRecordMerge()
    ActiveDocument.Variables("SuperV").Value = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Supervisor").Value
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me a) where this needs to go and b) what it might need to contain to make it actually run?

If I run the subroutine manually, it works as expected on the active MailMerge record.

Comment: Just wrote a whole answer over half an hour and realized there was a way easier way. Updating now.

Answer (score 0):

Its not surprising you're having difficulty with this one. In order to access the event you need (which is the `MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge` Event), you need access to the Application Object.

This is relatively easy to do:

```
'declare global Application reference
Dim WithEvents wdApp As Application
```

'set the reference somewhere (I've used Document_Open, but you can use whatever you want)

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

    'Get a reference to the Word application to handle mail merge events.
    Set wdApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub wdApp_MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge(ByVal doc As Document)
    Debug.Print ("MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge")

End Sub

'clean up
Private Sub Document_Close()
    wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

A couple of good examples are in the old MS docs fr Word 2002 (they still word in 2013):
[Word 2002 MailMerge event code demonstration](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285333)

Comment: Hmm, I've tried that and while it doesn't throw any debugging errors it doesn't actually appear to be running the code within the wdApp_MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge() sub.

I stuck a msgbox("Run!") in there to see if it was running the routine at all, and it doesn't appear it's being run at all - I'm not sure why though.

Comment: @bbk did you get any further with this? I have not had any luck either

Answer (score 0):

Complete working example updated for Word 2016

```
'declare global Application reference
Dim WithEvents wdApp As Application
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Debug.Print ("Document_Open")
    'Get a reference to the Word application to handle mail merge events.
    Set wdApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub wdapp_MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print ("MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge")

End Sub

Private Sub Document_Close()
    Debug.Print ("Document_Close")
    wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you've changed from [leemo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23901345/622391) and why you've changed it.